How different do you sound when you use a semicolon instead of a period?
Through my time using the site, I've seen native speakers use semicolons from time to time, but I don't really know why they made that choice. Look at these three examples:


The smoking rate for women jumped from 100 per 1000 in 1960 to 300 in 1975; it remained at this level for the next five years.
The smoking rate for women jumped from 100 per 1000 in 1960 to 300 in 1975. It remained at this level for the next five years.
The smoking rate for women jumped from 100 per 1000 in 1960 to 300 in 1975, and it remained at this level for the next five years.


Is there any noteworthy difference between these examples? Why would one choose (1) instead of (2) or (3)?

The answer is the same as in the duplicate.  Semicolons are stylistic choice that you might use to indicate that two sentences are closely linked.  (often by an implied "so" or "although")

How about "and"? The two phrases are linked in terms of order in time, one happened after another. I'm not sure if that's considered closely linked.

The following interpretation may be too subtle by half (I may be imagining it), but the semicolon version seems to me a bit better if this is a topic sentence and the material that follows is going to be about the rate of smoking in women. The other two might be a little better, though, if the next sentence were, say, “By contrast, traffic fatalities among women drivers…”  But your three versions are nearly identical in interpretation.

Like in the duplicate, you can use two sentences (no particular linkage between the clauses)  or a semicolon (there is linkage, the nature of which must be infered from context) or you can use a conjunction (there is linkage, the nature of which is explicit from the choice of conjunction)
